# Is there a way to get all the static fields and its values from different class dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, static

I need to get static values from different class on the initialization of the application, I'm using @PostConstruct and I don't know how to retrieve all these values without creating an instance of each class

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: static members belong to the class instead of a specific instance, so I don't understand why do you need to create objects

Comment: Because I need to do it dynamically, I can't ask for specific classes or attributes, I need a way to find all of this automatically, maybe with inheritance on the class with the static fields, but that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could user reflection (Class name can be even dynamically passed):

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        printStaticFieldsAndValues("com.example.ClassWithStaticFields");
    }

    private static void printStaticFieldsAndValues(String className)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
        for (Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + f.getName());
                System.out.println("Value " + f.get(null));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class which has static fields:

```
package com.example;

public class ClassWithStaticFields {

    static String stringField = "String Value";

}
```

Output:

```
Name: stringField
Value String Value
```

Comment: This is really close, but there's a way to retrieve all the classes with the static fields automatically? Without the name of the class.

Comment: Using reflection library, you should be able to get all classes based on package name - https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections. Please refer Addendum section of accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try static initializer on the class

```
public class OtherClass {

   public static final String VALUE = "SomeValue";

}

public class SomeClass {

   static {
      OtherClass.VALUE;
   }
}
```

And do whatever you want.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use the specific class which contains the static field, I have to find all these static fields, automatically